# CSS selector for grouping elements by 2 and 3 per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, grid

I have a list of elements I want to style 2 and 3 per row alternatively. Ideally I want a CSS solution.

Regardless of using float, flex, or grid, there is still the issue of the CSS selector.

I was initially thinking of using something like :nth-child(n+3) and :nth-child(n+2) but that made no sense.

This is the style I'm using right now, but I'm looking for a more dynamic solution.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.element > div {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
}

.element:nth-child(1),
.element:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
}

.element:nth-child(3),
.element:nth-child(4),
.element:nth-child(5) {
    width: 33%;
}

.element:nth-child(6),
.element:nth-child(7) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would using `:nth-child` selectors not make sense?

Comment: So what did you try? Where is your CSS?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that using n+2 and n+3 didn't make sense. Added my current CSS to the question.

Comment: you pattern repeat each 5 element so you need `nth-child(5n + x)`

Comment: Temani was very close, in case anyone needs it, this is the solution I went with `.row:nth-child(5n-4), .row:nth-child(5n-3) { width: 50%; } .row:nth-child(5n), .row:nth-child(5n-1), .row:nth-child(5n-2) { width: 33%; }`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle, this might be what you're looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/xch0m5zy/

```
.box:nth-child(-n+3) {
 background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(n+4) {
 background-color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(n+7) {
 background-color: green;
}
```